# To better understand recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am making an attempt to learn recursion better so I have been practicing some problems.

A common problem is flatten an list of lists to a single list. For example

```
[3,4,[1,2]] so the desired result will be [3,4,1,2].
```

The way I am approaching the problem is:

1. is 0 element a list - no
2. is 1 element a list - no
3. is 2 element a
   list - yes

   call the function again and do tests again

My base case will be to return if element is not a list.

Is there a better approach to understand recursion better?

Comment: That seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is in the right direction, but you should not check more than the first element. In general - a "pure" recursive solution will only have to look at the "head" of the list (first element), and the "tail" (`list[1:]`).

something like (python like pseudo code):

```
def flatten(l):
  if len(l) == 0:
     return []  
  if isinstance(l[0], list):
     left = flatten(l[0])
  else:
     left = [l[0]]
  return left + flatten(l[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You example is certainly one that works however it may be slightly too simple for you to get a full understanding.  I found that maze problems were the most helpful in me understanding recursive problems.  The main preface is there is a 2x2 array consisting of two different values.  One value denotes a wall within the maze and the other value denotes empty space.  Your job would be to traverse through the maze using recursion.  Here is an example problem and solution:

https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Let me look into this. Thanks for the great suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should.

1. Create a new list (passed) before calling function. Call function.
2. Loop through the old one and check if the type of list if so, then call function recursive.
3. else add element to passed list.

---

```
aList = [3,4,[1,2]]

def flatten(inList,outList):
    for elem in inList:
        if isinstance(elem,list):
            flatten(elem,outList)
        else:
            outList.append(elem)

bList = list()
flatten(aList,bList)
print bList
```

Comment: Passing an empty mutable type to a function is generally a bad idea. If it is used as a positional argument, why pass it at all? Just have the function create one and return it. If is used as a default argument you will get some pretty unexpected results as the list is not recreated each time you call the function. It is created once when the program starts and each subsequent run of that function will return the same list, with all the elements in it form the previous run.

Comment: I said nothing about default arguments. That would cause a problem as you stated . The empty list allows the answer to grow with each addition and be passed to recursive calls. If not passed the lists have to be contaminated together which is OK as well.

Comment: If you are going to be changing a value you should return the new value not   implicitly changing a parameter inside a function. Having to create a new empty list prior to using this function is an odd requirement.